# Lua Virtual Machine Register size

Tags: lua, vm-implementation

In the register based lua virtual machine are the registers fixed size?
Or is it a dynamic structure?

I found an bytecode example here at page 17 where the constant string "hello" is loaded into a register, so it must be dynamic? Isn't this uncommon for registers?

http://luaforge.net/docman/83/98/ANoFrillsIntroToLua51VMInstructions.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each register contains a Lua value. Lua values are implemented in C as tagged unions. See also: [The Implementation Of Lua 5.0](http://www.lua.org/doc/jucs05.pdf). This tagged union stores small types (booleans, numbers) by value and everything else (strings, tables, functions, etc.) as a pointer. So the size of a register is constant, though larger than one native machine word.

Comment: So if afterwards another instruction is done on the Register with the pointer the operation is done on the pointer?

Comment: @TM90 The register will contain the pointer, but the operation will usually act on the object it points to, not on the pointer.